# Remove translucent black shadow programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've come across this very weird issue which I cannot reproduce in any other XCode project. As you can see in this video.

https://youtu.be/2CG72ZoY1Is

Its a strange black shadow laying underneath of the translucent navbar. Does anyone know a way to solve it? Programmatically or storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: vote up please :))